# Integrating MySQLdb with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have my path to the MySQLdb source folder I downloaded using apt-get install python-mysqldb. When I run the import from the command line, it works fine:
[image: command line]

I then set my Eclipse PyDev plugin settings to go to the folder containing the MySQLdb stuff:
[image: pydev path settings]

But my editor is still unable to get rid of the error, even after closing/opening the file and restarting Eclipse:
[image: fail]

Here's what's contained at that directory (maybe I'm adding the wrong stuff to the path?:
[image: directory]

Does anyone see anything I'm doing wrong or can provide me some insight on how I can get this thing to work within Eclipse PyDev?

Thanks,
Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the python interpreter from the pydev preferences dialog in eclipse, saving the changes, then re-adding the same python interpreter.